# Slideshow page centered with different image sizes

Tags: jquery, slideshow, html, center, css-position

I have a Slideshow, vertically/horizontally centered in the page (by window-resize jquery).

It works fine with images of the same size.
But how does this work, if I want images of different sizes to be centered
vertically/horizontally in the div?

Update:
I managed to solve it. Here is the JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/mihaene/FSeAe/3/

The solution was to give this properties to the IMG in the centered DIV:

```
margin:auto; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
```

I'm not sure, but maybe, this can be done in a simpler way. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Call the resize method on slideshow navigation click.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't seem to work. What do I have to do with the CSS? Somehow the image size must be defined, so it allows different image-sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css which will work for images with size less than div #slideshow

```
#slideshow img { margin:0 auto;}
```

I use following method which I have written to get resize dimensions.

```
function resizeDimensions(oldW, oldH, nuW, nuH){

        // resize according to given width
        if(nuW!=null){
                nuH = (oldH*nuW)/oldW;
            }
        else
        if(nuH!=null)   // resize according to given Height
            {
                nuW = (nuH*oldW)/oldH;
            }

         var dimensions = new Array(nuW, nuH);
     return dimensions;

     }
```

Comment: I don't really get it, sorry. I am kind of a beginner. I put together a JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mihaene/FSeAe/